# Oracle Apex: Success With compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a procedure named "Greetings"  in the oracle apex. The Procedure Greetings runs with some error throwing up called "Success with compilation error". Is there anything wrong with my below code.

Code:

```
create table tb_Animals (
    txt_Name varchar(20) Primary Key,
    int_Weight number
);

insert into tb_Animals values ('Dog',30);
insert into tb_Animals values ('Cat',15);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings 
AS 
BEGIN 
   select * from tb_Animals;
END;
```

Comment: Which database do you really use? Is it both MySQL and Oracle? If not, please, remove the one you don't use.

Comment: I've removed mySql. I used oracle.

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL, you have to insert those values **into** something, usually a variable, However, if you're selecting the whole table contents, then it has to be something else; one option might be a refcursor. For example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings
  2  AS
  3    rc sys_refcursor;
  4  BEGIN
  5    open rc for
  6     select * from tb_Animals;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

It is now *correct* as far as *compilation* is concerned, but - actual "solution" depends on what you really want to do.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer.  Can you explain what actually does the sys_refcursor and open rc do?

Comment: You're welcome. It is a *weak* ref cursor; it accepts any result set. OPEN is the way to actually "put" result of that SELECT statement into it.

Comment: Thanks mate But I've seen people doing the queries without ref_cursor in a procedure. Here's https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/select-insert-update-delete-using-stored-procedure-in-sql/ .

Comment: how is it possible?

Comment: I never said that refcursor is the only way; it is just **one option**, and there are others available. The one you'll choose depends on - as I said - what you want to do once you select all rows from tb_animals table.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see here:

1. The code you provided is a SQL script that will *create* the procedure, not *run* the procedure. The error is telling you that the procedure has been created, but that it has an error. You can see the precise error by entering "SHOW ERRORS" at the sqlplus prompt after the create command completes.
2. The problem with the procedure itself is that you have to *do* something with the data you've selected. It needs to be processed into variables, or used in a for/next loop for some purpose. Simply selecting data into nothing won't work - PL/SQL is a programming language, not a scripting language. See here for a beginner's guide: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/introduction-to-plsql. I can't offer any more specific guidance than that since you've not provided any info on what your procedure is actually trying to do.

If you just want your *script* to return the data you just inserted into the table as a confirmation, just run the select statement without the procedural stuff, like this (and don't forget to commit your changes!):

```
create table tb_Animals (
    txt_Name varchar(20) Primary Key,
    int_Weight number
);

insert into tb_Animals values ('Dog',30);
insert into tb_Animals values ('Cat',15);
commit;

select * from tb_Animals;
```

Comment: But I've seen people execute queries like insert values in a table, or select a table in a procedure.

Comment: how is that possible then?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/select-insert-update-delete-using-stored-procedure-in-sql/

Comment: Your example is for SQL Server, not Oracle. Not the same thing.